# Compare Values Between Two Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I Have two tables, **Table_A** and **Table_B**.

I want result like the table **result** below, can someone help me with the SQL query?

Table_A

```
------------------
ID  ITEM_ID   QTY
------------------
1   100        2
2   101        3
3   102        5
4   103        2
------------------
```

Table_B

```
------------------
ID  ITEM_ID   QTY
1   100        2
2   101        4
3   102        4
4   104        2
5   105        1
------------------
```

RESULT

```
------------------
ITEM_ID   QTY
100        0
101        1
102        -1
103        -2
104        2
105        1
------------------
```

Thanks.

Comment: What query do you have so far?

Comment: what is the logic you want for creating the result? It looks like you want to be subtracting the quantity for item in table_B from the quantity for the same item in table_A.  Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a full join to get values from either table

```
 select
      isnull(a.item_id,b.item_id) as item_id, isnull(b.qty, 0) - isnull(a.qty, 0) as qty
    from
      table_a a
      full outer join table_b b on a.item_id = b.item_id
```

Comment: @Firdaus out of curiousity, what works faster, the full outer join, or summing both tables by a union (as shown in my response)?

Comment: I don't have large database records to prove what the fastest method... :)

Comment: Well it has a cleaner execution plan... just saying

Answer (score 0):

```
select item_id, sum(qty)
  from (select item_id, qty
          from table_b
        union all
        select item_id, -qty
          from table_a) x
 group by item_id
 order by item_id
```

Comment: @weenoid this will include items from one but not both tables.

Comment: A creative solution.  I am not sure how well it would scale however.

Comment: @paqogomez how long does it take to run?

Comment: If you compare the fiddles this uses 2 table scans whereas the full outer join uses 4.

Comment: A fine solution, not sure why it got downvoted.  Perhaps add some commentary?

Answer (score 0):

Used full outer join and some isnulls

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/142e6/2)

```
select isnull(b.item_id, a.item_id) as ItemID,
  isnull(b.qty, 0) - isnull(a.qty,0)as Qty
from table_b b
full outer join table_a a on a.item_id = b.item_id
order by itemid
```

Comment: It's works two bro... little different with @JamieA but It's works.
thanks